# How to retrieve this list of requests with the status of each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I am a new ASP.NET Webforms developer. I am learning now how to use the Entity Framework and Repository Pattern. What I am struggling with right now is how to retrieve the list of requests from a TRequest table with the status of the approval of each request. Here's my database schema:

```
TRequest: Id, Title, Reason
TApproval: Id, RequestId, StatusId
TStatus: Id, Title
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the list of requests including the status of each request.

In my repository pattern, I have the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<TRequest> GetRequest()
{
    return context.TRequest.ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<TRequest> GetRequestByStatus(int statusId)
{
    return GetRequests().Where(r => r.TApproval.TStatus.Id).ToList();   //I got an error here
}
```

**Why Am I getting error in the second method GetRequestByStatus?** I am unable to say `r.TApproval.TStatus.Id` and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

> Why Am I getting error in the second method GetRequestByStatus? I am unable to > say r.TApproval.TStatus.Id and I don't know why.

The `Where` method expects a predicate and you don't pass a predicate there. More formally, as it is stated in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx).

> The where clause is used in a query expression to specify which
>   elements from the data source will be returned in the query
>   expression. **It applies a Boolean condition (predicate) to each source**
>   **element (referenced by the range variable) and returns those for which**
>   **the specified condition is true**. A single query expression may contain
>   multiple where clauses and a single clause may contain multiple
>   predicate subexpressions.

Comment: thanks for your trying to help me. I know this but which I really don't know is how to resolve my issue explained above.

Comment: @TechLover you are welcome. So, there is something odd here. As I can see the `TRequest` has not any reference to the `TApproval`. That being said I don't think that you want is feasible by querying the `TRequest` table. That's the odd think. On the other hand, I can assume that you can get that you want by querying the `TApproval` table and Include in the results the corresponding `TRequest`. I think that something like this `context.TApproval.Inlcude(appr=>appr.TRequest)` might be helpful to your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter by status id you will need to change the line to

```
return GetRequests().Where(r => r.TApproval.TStatus.Id == statusId).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The problem is I can't add `TStatus`. I am getting error underneath this line of code and I don't know why.